# Can I cut off a thermocouple's metal head?

Tags: thermocouple

I want to attach a thermocouple to my 40Watt soldering iron in order to make it temperature controlled. The thermocouple I'm going to buy is a K type MAX6675 thermocouple that looks like this:
[image]

But the thing is it has this bulky metal head attached to it which doesn't seem to be detachable. Since I want to attach the thermocouple to my soldering iron the smaller it is the better for my application.

I was wondering if I could just cut off the metal head of the MAX6675, twist the heads of the wires together and turn it into something like this:
[image]

Will the thermocopule stay intact if I do such thing?

And if not, is there any other way I can get rid of that bulky head? (Buying another thermocopule is not an option)

Comment: If you can weld the two wires together at the end, you can re-create the thermocouple junction. Just twisting them together is not likely to work.

Comment: Regardless of the question, an add-on thermocouple approach is impractical from a mechanical/heat transfer perspective if you want to do meaningful soldering with the result.  If you want to make a thermocouple controlled soldering iron, buy a replacement tip for a design that includes a thermocouple along with the heater in the tip.  3rd party tips compatible with the Hakko T12 series seem among the most inexpensive, and even the genuine ones aren't that costly, but probably best to overtemp an imitation while getting your controller sorted out.

Comment: @ChrisStratton why is an add-on thermocouple impractical? I'm planning to turn the iron off when it passes a certain temperature and turn it on again when it falls below a certain temperature.

Comment: The practical performance of a soldering iron is heavily tied to having the temperature sensor rapidly respond when the working part of the tip looses heat.  This means that the sensor needs to be very close to the tip, not buried in something larger with a lot of thermal mass.  For a "science-fair" type project you could perhaps try cross-drilling the base of a tip and embedding the sensor somehow, but if you want to make a usable tool, buy a tip with a sensor embedded near its working part. Otherwise no matter how much trouble you go to with the electronics, you'll be getting bad data.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Yes I see. I had not thought of the speed that the tip loses heat. I think I need a more sensitive measurement than I thought. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: I'm very happy with the chinese T12. Wish it was available 30 years ago. Remember that an external thermocouple will have to be insulated from heat loss or ambient airflow. So it will have to be wrapped on the tip with some thermal conductor and then wrapped with some thermal insulator. Makes it all bulky, and in the end the poor regulation may not be worth it. The smaller the tip and heater, the less it loses heat. So, even a manually controlled variable wattage micro soldering pen works out much better than a big high wattage iron.

Comment: @ThePhoton -- I think the law of intermediate metals says that you should be able to braze them together. Full welding shouldn't be necessary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you should be able to cut the wires and reattach them without losing calibration.  I wouldn't necessarily just twist them up, though.  A weld would be best, and brazing second best (http://eleceng.dit.ie/gavin/Instrument/Temperature/Laws%20of%20ThermoC.html -- the law of intermediate metals can be used to show this).  A blob of solder is sort of like a braze.  Even a bad solder is likely good enough.

Twisting will give you some life, but it may not be gas-tight.  I'd be concerned about oxidation eventually causing intermittent connections.  Crimping should work too, in a pinch, and there are gas-tight ways to crimp.

https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/okay-to-twist-thermocouple-wires.793193/#post-4982730

Reference https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/okay-to-twist-thermocouple-wires.793193/

Comment: Citations from Internet can give a lot of confused opinions, like this total delirium from an alleged professional site, http://www.capgo.com/Resources/Temperature/thermocouple/thermocouple.html The site alleges that the output of a thermocouple depends on gradient of temperature along the wires near the joint, citing Thomson Effect. This would be true if the measurement schema would use any significant current flow. In reality the measuring micro-voltmeters have very high input impedance, and currents along the wires are zero. Careful what do you read on Internet.

Comment: However, in fact, the Thermocouple reading do depend on longitudinal gradient, but not because of Thomson effect, but because if the bulk of wires is exposed to a different temperature of ambient, the heat will flow along the wires, and change the actual temperature of the thermocouple tip. So the first rule of thermocouple placement on objects is to lay them along isotherms as much as you can.

Comment: The only point I'm trying to cite from that site is the Law of Intermediate Metals, which is a Law

Answer (score 3):

> Will the thermocopule stay intact if I do such thing?

I'd argue that "intactness" is broken the moment you cut something off.

Functionally: the contact of the two different metals is indeed what gives the thermovoltage.

> The thermocouple **I'm going to buy** is a K type MAX6675 thermocouple that looks like this: 
> …
>    (Buying another thermocopule is not an option)

(emphasis by me)

I call nonsense on that. You need a differently sized thermocouple head. You can buy hundreds of others out there.

So, get a different thermocouple.

Comment: I agree. Buying the *correct* thermocouple is priority, and you'd better MAKE it an option.

Comment: I've made *ad hoc* thermocouple probes by twisting the wires together and securing the twist with a solder blob.  The thermocouple worked.  Its accuracy didn't degrade.  So, I can't confirm your point about not introducing other metals.  (How well solder would stick to thermocouple materials?  Does solder lower the practical temperature at which the thermocouple assembly can work?  Those are valid but separate questions.)

Comment: @NickAlexeev I can see how the Lead1-solder-Lead2 double-junction should effectively have the same voltage as the Lead1-Lead2 junction, thinking about this. But I'm afraid that an oxide (or flux) layer between lead1 and 2 would actually be pretty detrimental, at the very least to the current sourcing capability of the junction, so I'm aware that I'm wrong, but kiiiiinda hesitant to say "sure, just go ahead".

Comment: @MarcusMüller Thanks for your answer. That's the only inexpensive thermocouple I could find online where I'm from. Also I haven't calibrated anything, I haven't bought it yet. How much error are we talking about? I don't need very precise measurements.

Comment: Where are you from? Really, mouser and digikey really deliver almost everywhere on this earth. By saying "can't consider a different one", you've been hiding your real problem, namely that you need a different one!

Comment: No there are places on this earth where you can't buy anything from outside. Anyway, I'm probably going to cancel this project, unless I find one that is small enough to fit very well inside the heating element because of what you and ChrisStratton said.

Comment: To think that there would be an oxide or flux layer between the metals and electrically in series with their contact is a fundamental misunderstanding of what the soldering process does when successful.  Granted, it is possible to stick a blob of cold solder on something without it wetting, but that is "making a mess with a soldering iron", not soldering.    The role of flux is to dissolve oxides and transport them to the exterior of the joint

Comment: Recycling wire from a thermocouple to make another is possible with results ranging from professional to temporary depending on how it is done.  The actual problem here is that even a nice compact welded-bead thermocouple isn't going to work very well with an off-the-shelf solder tip *during soldering*, though it could be used to cross-check an iron's own control loop while evaluating that tool.

Comment: @ChrisStratton no doubt, if perfectly soldered, no such boundary. However, don't think thermocouple wire accepts any solder I've used.

Comment: A thermocouple is a thermocouple is a thermocouple.  Every thermocouple of the same type has the same calibration (though different time constants due to thermal mass).  I wouldn't just twist them up.  Solder -- even a bad solder -- should be OK, by the Law of Intermediate Metals.

Comment: I agree with @ScottSeidman, this answer is misleading.

Comment: This answer is incorrect. Metal contamination will NOT effect the thermocouple junction.

Answer (score 2):

You can do anything with thermocouple wires as long as you can figure out how to WELD the tip of thermocouple. Soldering is a bad option.

You shouldn't worry much about "calibration", especially for the soldering iron application, because the voltage output is determined by metal alloy compositions of the two wires, and by nothing else.

If you would require results to a fraction of a degree C, then it is always wise to get your own calibration curve.

Comment: Soldering should be good enough in a pinch.

Comment: Obviously, if it falls apart, life is compromised.  It's the mechanical connection that counts, though, not the electrical.

Comment: @ScottSeidman, soldering can be fine as long as the wire alloys stick with solder alloy (wet surface, can't find proper term), which is usually VERY hard to achieve. Much easier and reliable is to design a micro-welder. Especially if this is a high-temperature soldering iron application.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, theoretically that will work; mechanical issues aside.

Marcus Müller's answer warns that metal contamination of the junction will effect the thermocouples accuracy; but that's not correct. If you introduce a dissimilar metal you're basically creating 2 thermocouple junctions at the point: A-B-C. Well it turns out that if both junctions A-B, and B-C are at the same temperature the effect of B cancels out, and it's equivalent to A-C. So no, a little metal from your pliers will not ruin the thermocouple junction.

You can check out this document for more in depth information (see page 5): https://www.omega.com/temperature/Z/pdf/z021-032.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Back in the day at AT&T Power Systems we would just twist the bare wires together and then solder the twist for a mechanical bond.  We would wire up hunderds of TC's to a power rack and record the data on a rack of data loggers.  The solder method worked great back then.